# Developer payload verification fail on purchase, what to do next

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm implementing the Google Play In-app Billing v3 into my app and have now stumbled on a question I just don't found any answers for and I think Google lacks a bit information about.

The products that will be available for purchase within my app will be consumed directly(donations) and I'm going to use the `developerPayload` only for verification of the purchase just to ensure the response of the purchase is the same as the request sent. But the thing I just can't find any answers to is those cases the `developerPayload` verification fails? What to do then, because even though the verification fails the purchase could have been successfully made. So what seems most logic here would be to rollback the purchase and refund the money but there doesn't seem to be any support for that in the IAB v3 API.

What's the correct way of handle these situations?

Comment: Why would you use the payload for verification and if the purchase was successful but the payload differ, roll it back? I would suggest to just *not* unlock the bought content and send a message to your server, for further investigation. Because a difference in the payload indicates that the purchase was cheated.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the official Google Documentation about Verification:

***When your application receives this signed response you can use the public key portion of your RSA key pair to verify the signature. By performing signature verification you can detect responses that have been tampered with or that have been spoofed. You can perform this signature verification step in your application; however, if your application connects to a secure remote server then we recommend that you perform the signature verification on that server.***

So the point where you find the signature verification is being tempered. You can issue a refund. Although there is no programmatic way to do it as far as I know, you need to do that manually.

Comment: Maybe the way to go is to just inform the user that the purchase was made but  verification of it couldn't be done. Then it's up to the user to make a if she/he want's to contact the developer for further investigation, most probably a refund. This maybe doesn't happens that often but I think this bit could be a bit more described in the documentation.